# how to filter an object and get the desired output in javascript array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of object like this,

```
[
  {imgUrl: "A"},
  {imgUrl: "B"},
  {imgUrl: "C", file: {fileName: "D"} }  
]
```

Desired output = ["A", "B", "D"];

Comment: Hi, this is not a valid object. There are syntax errors.

Comment: really? can you you explain how?

Comment: @kaws A JavaScript object is a collection of named values, here you have only arrays, not key value pairs

Comment: Not a valid object, Please reply with valid object, then it's easy to parse and get what you want.

Comment: You probably mix [] and {}

Comment: this is an aray of object

Comment: @kaws This is not.

Comment: sorry that was my mistake. dint notice. it is changed.

Comment: @kaws You could verify that this is not a valid object fairly easily. Just open developer tools, got to the console and copy/paste your code and press enter, you will note the following error message `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: It's valid now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to make use of the `map` Array's method.

```js
var input = [
  {imgUrl: "A"},
  {imgUrl: "B"},
  {imgUrl: "C", file: {fileName: "D"} }   
];

var output = input.map(function(item){
    return item.file 
         ? item.file.fileName
         : item.imgUrl;
});

console.log(output)
```

Comment: i want a, b and d as output

Comment: Tnx. I just noticed that my object in my editor is different than that i posted here. i modified my question. Your answer didnt solve it.

Comment: @kaws It wasn't needed a big change.

Comment: can you explain, what the below method does?
return item.file ? item.file.name : item.imgUrl;

Comment: @kaws This is the conditional (ternary operator), https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator. Generally, if `item.file` is truthy then it's `fileName` property value is returned. Otherwise the `imgUrl` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
let yourResult = [
  {imgUrl: "A"},
  {imgUrl: "B"},
  {imgUrl: "C", fileName: "D"}  
].reduce((result, item) => {
    result.push(item.fileName ? item.fileName : item.imgUrl);
    return result;
}, []);
```

Comment: is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Well, using the `reduce` method on your array is quite the state of the art. What more would you expect? You can use `map` too, it's quite the same for that kind of need.

Comment: can you explain this line?
result.push(item.fileName ? item.fileName : item.imgUrl);

Comment: you push in the result array either `item.fileName` if it is defined, else you push `item.imgUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want the imgUrl of a value array, unless a fileName is present?  If that's the case, there are loads of ways that you can achieve this, but using the [reduce functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), you can do something like this:

```
test = [
  {imgUrl: "A"},
  {imgUrl: "B"},
  {imgUrl: "C", file: {fileName: "D"}},  
]

output = test.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  return acc.concat([obj.file && obj.file.fileName || obj.imgUrl])
}, [])
```

The || statement here will prioritize the obj.file.fileName iff obj.file exists: if it's a valid value it will just return that value, but if the value is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) it will instead take the value of obj.imgUrl

Sidenote on "Falsy": 
If you do what to consider empty strings or zero values or any value as valid values, you can replace the || statement with a [Ternary Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

i.e.
condition ? if_true_return_value : if_false_return_value

In this case:

(obj.[hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)("file") && obj.file.fileName) ? obj.file.fileName : obj.imgUrl

Comment: can you run this in fiddle?

Comment: Nice explanation. I just noticed that my object in my editor is different than that i posted here.  i modified my question. Your answer didnt solve it.

Comment: Please check this fiddle.

Comment: I suspect that you've already found your answer, but to target one level deeper, you'd simply use `obj.file.fileName` instead of `obj.fileName` as you want to target the value denoted by the key "fileName" inside of an object value denoted by the key "file"

Comment: Woops, sorry about that, fixed above if you still need it and here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qhg5xsfd/2/

Comment: Thanks for you effort. I really appreciate. Good luck. God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a proxy to handle the cases when you need the properties with some sort of priority. Though for this case I would not recommend it. This answer is simply an example.

```js
// get handler arguments (t,p) is t for target (the arr) and p for property is the property
// of array we are trying to get. this could be 0 as an index or a function name
const arr =[{a: "A"},{a: "B"}, {a: "C", b: "D"} ];
const arrP = new Proxy(arr,{ // add get proxy name to return map of names
        get : (t, p)=> p==="names" ? t.map(o => o.b ? o.b : o.a ): t[p]
    }
);
console.log(arrP.names);
```

Or you can use  `Proxy.revocable`

```
const arrPr = Proxy.revocable(arr,{
    get : (t, p)=> p==="names" ? t.map(o => o.b ? o.b : o.a ): t[p]
});
console.log(arrPr.proxy.names);
arrPr.revoke();  // can use anymore will throw if you try.
```

Comment: Tnx. I just noticed that my object in my editor is different than that i posted here. i modified my question. Your answer didnt solve it.